# Too few arguments to function ,1 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, router

Hola al parecer tengo un error en mi controller de cobranza lo cual ya intente de todo pero aun no encuentro el error, si pudieran ayudarme seria de buen gesto :/.
Estoy intentando crear una cobranza de un empleado por lo que necesito su id para identificar al usuario de la cual creare su cobranza y los demas datos que aparecen en mi metodo.

Al momento de registrar me aparece este error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

public function formCrear(){
        return view('caja1.crear-cobranza');
    }

```
public function registrarCobranza(Request $request, $id){

    $cobranza = cobranza::find($id);
    $cobranza->usuario_id=$request-> usuario_id;
    $cobranza->monto = $request-> monto;
    $cobranza->fecha =  $request-> fecha;
    $cobranza->estatus = $request-> estatus;
      $cobranza-> save();
      $cobranza = cobranza ::all();


      return view('caja1.cobranza',compact('cobranza'));

      return redirect('cobranza');
}
```

Tal vez tengo ayuda en mis rutas o porque  2 esperando?

Comment: El mensaje parece claro: `registrarCobranza()`  espera dos parámetros: la referencia a `Request` y el `$id`, pero le estás pasando un solo parámetro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error es claro:

> Too few arguments to function, 1 passed and exactly 2 expected"

Que significa:

> Muy pocos argumentos para la función, se pasó 1 pero se esperan exactamente 2

Si te fijas en la declaración de tu función, efectivamente espera dos argumentos:

```php
public function registrarCobranza(Request $request, $id) { /** ... */ }
```

Imagino que tú estás llamando ese método desde tus rutas y que la variable `$id` es un [parámetro de ruta (Route param)](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters). Entonces si tu ruta está definida del siguiente modo:

```php
Route::post('cobranzas/{id}/registrar', 'CobranzasController@registrarCobranza');
```

Puedes acceder al valor de ese parámetro de manera dinámica sin necesidad de incluirlo en la declaración de la función:

```php
public function registrarCobranza(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id; // accediendo dinámicamente al valor.
    // ...
}
```

---

## Plus

De hecho, puedes incluso hacer uso del [Enlazamiendo de modelo a rutas (Route model binding)](https://docs.laraveles.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding). La documentación señala:

> ### Enlazado implícito – Implicit binding
>
> Laravel resuelve de forma automática los modelos Eloquent que se
>   definen en rutas o acciones de controladores cuyo parámetro coincide
>   con el nombre de un segmento de la ruta. Por ejemplo:
>
> ```php
> Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
>     return $user->email;
> });
> ```
>
> Puesto que la variable `$user` se requiere como tipo de `App\User` y
>   el nombre de la variable coincide con el segmento URI `{user}`,
>   Laravel inyectará automáticamente la instancia de modelo que
>   corresponda con el valor de la petición URI. Si no se encuentra el
>   modelo en la base de datos, se generará una respuesta HTTP 404
>   automáticamente.

Aplicando lo anterior, si tienes tu ruta definida del siguietne modo:

```php
Route::post('cobranzas/{cobranza}/registrar', 'CobranzasController@registrarCobranza');
```

Como puedes notar, se ha definido el parámetro de ruta `{cobranza}` que recibirá el id de la cobranza. Laravel detectará esto y tratará de resolverlo con los modelos existentes, inyectando al controlador el modelo ya encontrado (equivalente a `Cobranza::find($id)`.

Entonces tu función puede ser declarada del siguiente modo:

```php
/** Nota que estamos inyectando el modelo resuelto en la firma del método */
public function registrarCobranza(Request $request, Cobranza $cobranza)
{
    $cobranza->usuario_id = $request-> usuario_id;
    $cobranza->monto = $request-> monto;
    $cobranza->fecha =  $request-> fecha;
    $cobranza->estatus = $request-> estatus;
    $cobranza-> save();

    $cobranzas = cobranza ::all();

    return view('caja1.cobranza',compact('cobranzas'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

De hecho el codigo quedaria mas refactorizado con un Request Personalizado donde definas explicitamente los campos que el usuario puede dar valor desde el formulario.

```
public function registrarCobranza(StoreRequest $r, Cobranza $c)
{
  $c->update($r->validated());
  return view('caja1.cobranza', [ 'cobranzas' => $c::all() ]);
}
```